# How to create a dataframe column with repeated string value?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading in data from a bunch of files and storing it in a data frame. I want a column of the data frame to indicate which file the data came from. How do I create a column that has the same string repeated over and over without typing it out manually?

Each file I'm reading in has ~100 data points (but not the same number each time). As I read each one in, I will concat to the dataframe along axis=0. It should look like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
numbers = np.random.randn(5) # this data could be of any length, ~100
labels = np.array(['file01','file01','file01','file01','file01']) 
tf = pd.DataFrame()
tf['labels'] = labels
tf['numbers'] = numbers

In [8]: tf
Out[8]: 
   labels   numbers
0  file01 -0.176737
1  file01 -1.243871
2  file01  0.154886
3  file01  0.236653
4  file01 -0.195053
```

(Yes, I know I could make 'file01' a column header and append each one along axis=1, but there are reasons I don't want to do it that way.)

Comment: IIUC you can just do `tf['labels'] = 'file01'` the scalar value will be broadcast along the minor axis of the df, besides why do you want to do this, it seems a little wasteful or are you wanting to just identify where the data comes from? you can just load the dfs into a df, set the `labels` column, append these to a list can call `pd.concat(list_of_dfs)`

Comment: When I did `tf['labels'] = 'file01'`, all of the labels came out as `NaN`.

Comment: You need a df with rows already populated, if your df is empty then doing the assignment doesn't expand the df, anyway you can do `tf = pd.DataFrame({'labels':labels, 'numbers':numbers'})`

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to identify where the data comes from. I had done this originally by having each file its own column, but it was really ugly because there were all these `NaN`s where the data sets were different lengths, and then I want to add more columns to each file and it was messy. I think concating length-wise will be cleaner.

Comment: Why not just populate a dict with the filename as the key and the dfs as the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go, your code is fixed! You can actually put a single value in the dict used in the DataFrame constructor :).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filename = 'file01'
numbers = np.random.randn(5) # this data could be of any length, ~100
tf = pd.DataFrame({'labels': filename , 'numbers': numbers})

In [8]: tf
Out[8]: 
   labels   numbers
0  file01 -0.176737
1  file01 -1.243871
2  file01  0.154886
3  file01  0.236653
4  file01 -0.195053
```

Comment: Thank you!! I knew this had to be easy, but still trying to wrap my head around all this syntax.

Comment: The constructor is pretty powerful, but I know pandas has a steep learning curve. Have you done their 10-minute tutorial?

Comment: Will pandas actually use the amount of memory needed to store each of the `file01` separately or is there some kind of pattern recognition built in that will make sure `file01` is stored only once and then reference all the cells to that same memory location?